# How to break through if statement inside a nested loop in java

Tags: java, label, break, goto, nested-if

While solving a problem on java I am finding trouble breaking through the if statement which is inside a for loop and this for loop is inside another if statement. The code fragment is as below:

```
package experment;
public class myclass_2{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  int t;
  int remaining;
  boolean is_undertaker_dead = false;
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("hey");
  t = s.nextInt();
  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
      String S = Integer.toString(s.nextInt());
      char c[] = S.toCharArray();
      for(int j=0; j<c.length; j++)
      {
          if(c[j]=='2')
          {
              remaining = c.length-j;
              for(int a=j; a<c.length; a++)
              {
                  if(remaining<c.length)
                      {
                      remaining=0;
                  }
                  if(c[j+remaining]=='1')
                  {
                     is_undertaker_dead=true;
                     break;
                  }
                  remaining--;
              }
          }
      }
      if(is_undertaker_dead==true)
      { 
          System.out.println("The Streak is broken!");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("The streak");
      }
  }
 }
```

I want to break outside of all the for loops once the break statement is called. I know this just break out of the if statement but the loop still continues. I also tried using the label method which I find on stackoverflow and google, but they somehow didn't work and confused me even more. Thank you in advance for your support, it means a lot!

Comment: "I tried using the label method" — what did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: @sujatha Doing return would exit out of the rest of the method, and that may/may not be what he wants.  He may want to break out of that subsection of code within the method only.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer then he needs to put the part that he wants to be able to break from, into a separate method, so that return does exactly what he needs it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `break` doesn't break out of if statement, it breaks out of loops, in your case second `for` loop.

In your code, `break` breaks out of inner `for` loop. To break out of outer for loop, simply put below condition, just prior to the closing bracket of the outer loop

```
if (is_undertaker_dead)
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before the first loop:

```
mainloop:
```

and to break from all the loops, call this

```
break mainloop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a labeled version of break:

```
outerLoop:
for(int j=0; j<c.length; j++)
  {
      if(c[j]=='2')
      {
          remaining = c.length-j;
          for(int a=j; a<c.length; a++)
          {
              if(remaining<c.length)
                  {
                  remaining=0;
              }
              if(c[j+remaining]=='1')
              {
                 is_undertaker_dead=true;
                 break outerLoop;
              }
              remaining--;
          }
      }
  }
```

You can find more information and examples in the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).