# How to break if statement inside nested loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

Why my code don't stop when reach if statement, I want to break outside all loops once the break statement call, thanks before, sorry for my bad english

```
    for (int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <nums.length;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");System.out.println("Value : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                sum = nums[i]+nums[j];
                if(sum==target){
                    System.out.println("Result : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                    finalArray[0] = i;
                    finalArray[1] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break through if statement inside a nested loop in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653253/how-to-break-through-if-statement-inside-a-nested-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <nums.length;j++){
        if(i!=j){
            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");System.out.println("Value : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
            sum = nums[i]+nums[j];
            if(sum==target){
                System.out.println("Result : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                finalArray[0] = i;
                finalArray[1] = j;
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace `outer` with whatever you want.

Comment: *You can replace outer with whatever you want.* - well not really, also it should be `outer:`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Why can you not replace ```outer``` with whatever you want? Not hate, just curious.

Comment: I am guessing that you could not use reserved words - not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels to refer to loops like this:

```
loop1:        
for (int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j <nums.length;j++){
                if(i!=j){
                    System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");System.out.println("Value : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                    sum = nums[i]+nums[j];
                    if(sum==target){
                        System.out.println("Result : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                        finalArray[0] = i;
                        finalArray[1] = j;
                        break loop1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a flag in the inner loop when you want to break from the outer loop.
once inner loop breaks check if that flag is set, if it is, break from outer loop as well. Something like this:

```
boolean break_outer = false
for (int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <nums.length;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");System.out.println("Value : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                sum = nums[i]+nums[j];
                if(sum==target){
                    System.out.println("Result : "+nums[i]+" "+nums[j]);
                    finalArray[0] = i;
                    finalArray[1] = j;
                    break_outer = true
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (break_outer)
              break;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You already have quite a bit of code there. It seems to be getting something very specific for you. You could make it a method and have it return the values at that point.

2cents

I am not confident I have enough information to write the code. However, I'd like to try. With any luck it will give you something you need:

````java
private int[] convertToFinalArray(int[] nums, int target) {
    int sum = 0;

    int[] finalArray = new int[nums.length]; // I am inferring the length.
    for(int i = 0;i<nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
                System.out.println("Value : " + nums[i] + " " + nums[j]);
                sum = nums[i] + nums[j];
                if (sum == target) {
                    System.out.println("Result : " + nums[i] + " " + nums[j]);
                    finalArray[0] = i;
                    finalArray[1] = j;
                    return finalArray;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return finalArray;
}```
````

Comment: I did look at writing code, but the variables ```sum``` and ```target``` were unclear in terms of scope. Hence the 2cents.